# How do I output the debug view of a hash map to a text file in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a hash map and would like to put it into a text file. For printing  to the console, I would use `println`'s debug formatter to output the entire hash map.

Is there a similar method to do this for outputting to files? If not, what write method do you recommend? I have attempted a for loop and iterated through but i'm not sure if I should use `write_all` or just `write`.

Comment: Here is [the duplicate applied to your exact situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=8fc3afaa34b6891318cb6703c28f7ea6).